# AjaxFileUpload fails on UploadComplete

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm having trouble trying to get the AjaxFileUpload to complete properly.  Here's what happens:

1. Upon clicking 'Upload' the selected file is uploaded into a folder in C:\Windows\Temp\_AjaxFileUpload\
2. I have some code that creates a folder in my website directory for the current user and the file is saved in there.
3. The file is then deleted from the folder in C:\Windows\Temp\_AjaxFileUpload\
4. The UploadComplete process then fires again and when it reaches the AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs part the file is deleted from the folder in the website directory.
5. It then tries to access the file in the Temp folder (to delete it I assume), but can't because the file's already been deleted.  The error is:

   *Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP_AjaxFileUpload\E28925DA-BE0C-C1D3-8005-31B5698C6D4C\myfile.txt*

Here's the code I have:

```
    Protected Sub OnUploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete

       If Not Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads")) Then
           Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads"))
       End If

       Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName)

       AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads/" & fileName))

    End Sub
```

I have followed everything from here - [ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx)

but I cannot get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted in the end.  Through the advice of a post on another website I had added an additional line into the web.config.  Removing this solved the problem.